# Rsync strangely gets auto killed and then binary is broken

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

I got a strange situation with Rsync on my remote Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (Trusty Tahir) instance.

Whenever I execute it, it runs for a while (not completed) then seems get auto killed. After that it's broken (no binary `/usr/bin/rsync` anymore), purge and re-install then the same behaviour happens again.

```
rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh 'ssh  -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' '--out-format=<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' /tmp/production/tmp.CKlHWYgC6c/core/ /home/ubuntu/production/versions/build/prod-service_1.10.0_TEST/core/ 

<<CHANGED>>.d..t...... ./
<<CHANGED>>>f+++++++++ HOWTO.txt
<<CHANGED>>>f+++++++++ __init__.py
<<CHANGED>>>f+++++++++ app_store_customized.py
<<CHANGED>>>f+++++++++ av_appstore_package.py
<<CHANGED>>>f+++++++++ av_archive_file_handler.py
<<CHANGED>>>f+++++++++ av_build_relations.py
<<CHANGED>>>f+++++++++ av_build_ui_conditions.py
<<CHANGED>>>f+++++++++ av_cach.py
<<CHANGED>>>f+++++++++ av_countdown_caller.py
<<CHANGED>>>f+++++++++ av_glogin_dbsync.py
<<CHANGED>>>f+++++++++ av_local_module.py
<<CHANGED>>>f+++++++++ av_logger.py
...
...
<<CHANGED>>>f+++++++++ modules/av_cyren/avsdk/aivsecon-v2.def
<<CHANGED>>>f+++++++++ modules/av_cyren/avsdk/antivir-v2.def
<<CHANGED>>>f+++++++++ modules/av_cyren/avsdk/csamd
<<CHANGED>>>f+++++++++ modules/av_cyren/avsdk/csamd.conf
<<CHANGED>>>f+++++++++ modules/av_cyren/avsdk/libaivse000.so.5
Killed

ubuntu@ansible-tower-server:~$ rsync
-bash: /usr/bin/rsync: No such file or directory


ubuntu@ansible-tower-server:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge rsync && sudo apt-get install rsync
```

...

then try re-run rsync, it got auto killed again.

This is just happening recently, previously it ran properly. Any ideas?

**Updated 1:**
rsync version

```
rsync  version 3.1.0  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2013 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: http://rsync.samba.org/
Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, hardlinks, symlinks, IPv6, batchfiles, inplace,
    append, ACLs, xattrs, iconv, symtimes, prealloc
```

During rsync running (notice I haven't allocated swap for this instance)

```
ubuntu@ansible-tower-server:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7513       6467       1046         20        558       3909
-/+ buffers/cache:       1999       5514
Swap:            0          0          0
```

**Update 2**

I increase memory & swap, seems it's not a problem with memory

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         15042       3043      11998         19        326       1225
-/+ buffers/cache:       1492      13550
Swap:         7337          0       7337
```

re-run with -vvvv

here where it got killed (and lost the birary)

```
<<CHANGED>>>f+++++++++ modules/ap_cyren/ctasd/ctasd_initd
sending file_sum
false_alarms=0 hash_hits=0 matches=0
sender finished /tmp/avanan/tmp.fzMHAGBzXU/core/modules/ap_cyren/ctasd/ctasd_initd
send_files(474, /tmp/avanan/tmp.fzMHAGBzXU/core/modules/ap_cyren/ctasd/libaivse000.so)
count=0 n=0 rem=0
send_files mapped /tmp/avanan/tmp.fzMHAGBzXU/core/modules/ap_cyren/ctasd/libaivse000.so of size 2080872
calling match_sums /tmp/avanan/tmp.fzMHAGBzXU/core/modules/ap_cyren/ctasd/libaivse000.so
<<CHANGED>>>f+++++++++ modules/ap_cyren/ctasd/libaivse000.so
rsync: [receiver] write error: Broken pipe (32)
[receiver] _exit_cleanup(code=10, file=io.c, line=837): entered
Killed
renaming modules/ap_cyren/ctasd/.libaivse000.so.9Ar2ch to modules/ap_cyren/ctasd/.~tmp~/libaivse000.so
ubuntu@ansible-tower-server:~$ rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at io.c(837) [receiver=3.1.0]
[receiver] _exit_cleanup(code=10, file=io.c, line=837): about to call exit(10)
```

I tried with rsync of 2 simpler directories (less files) on the machine and it works fine. But just with above rsync (from a directory with more than 2000 files, including texts, biraries) it failed (furthermore, destroyed itself)

Comment: is per chance the av running on the system and trying to defend itself against malicious accesses to its files?

Comment: @JakeGould: yes I checked that thread but the issue on that seems regarding memory, also tried with some options suggested but no luck.

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann it's just a general Ubuntu 14.04 on EC2 so I don't think there's any AV running.

Comment: You are transferring files of an AV between two systems, don't you? If on any of those two systems the AV is running, this might be the culprit.

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann the command I'm testing is local, between two directories on the same machine

Comment: hmm, I see ... curious ...

Comment: You're not deleting or modifying `rsync` or `ssh` in the process of running the `rsync` command, are you?  Where is `rsync` located, and where are it's shared libraries located?

Comment: @Kusalananda how come rsync could be deleted by the process running rsync command? I test many times with just running plain rsync from command line, got same result. rsync obviously located at /usr/bin/rsync

Comment: `rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4092 bytes [sender]: Broken pipe (32)
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (8 bytes received so far) [sender]
_exit_cleanup(code=12, file=/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-47/rsync/io.c, line=453): entered
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-47/rsync/io.c(453) [sender=2.6.9]
_exit_cleanup(code=12, file=/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-47/rsync/io.c, line=453): about to call exit(255)`